# Global or Private variable initialized with value is visible through Java bytecode?

Tags: java, bytecode

If I initialize a global variable with a value like this:

```
private String name = "some name";
```

Would this be easily re-constructable thru .class file? I am trying to hide this value. How about if I make it a private variable inside some method, would this be unidentifiable thru a .class bytecode?

Please help.

Comment: Yes. Trivially. If you want to obscure it, encrypt or encode it.

Comment: In java, the private access modifier isn't designed as a security feature, but instead a way to help better organize your code. Doing so allows other developers to understand what's important to the object and what's available to the rest of the program, while also reducing mistakes where you may edit a var which is meant to stay exclusive to said class.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I think I wasn't able to explain my question better. I am trying to take a long shot. Let me try to explain again. I have a spring boot application that reads values from application.yaml. These are important keys. Spring injects them for me. Instead, I want to hardcode values to global variables. When I make a jar file of it, I will not include source files. This jar will only contain .class files. I am just trying to figure out that if I do this, would someone be able to guess those keys that I hardcoded?

Comment: **YES**. No guessing required. `javap -v Some.class` will show you all of the hardcoded strings in `Some.class`; encrypt or encode your sensitive `String`(s).

Comment: okay thanks @ElliottFrisch . Even if I encrypt it, people would still be able to see what encryption mechanism I am using. And then they will be able to guess it. No?

Comment: @Faraz Yes. Even if your encrypt (or just obscure) it, nothing is irreversible if you ever access it in your program. Just (slightly) more difficult.

Comment: Thank you Mr. @ElliottFrisch. I am thinking to take a different approach.

Comment: You have convinced me.